# jq to convert text strings and add them into an existing json object

Tags: json, bash, sh, text-processing, jq

How do I convert text strings and add them into an existing json object

Current json output:

```
{
  "start process": "Wed May 24 05:22:35 UTC 2017",
  "logfilename": "log_test"
}
{
  "start filelist": [
    "/downloads/json_log_array2object.jq",
    "/downloads/json_log_string2object.jq",
    "/downloads/log_test.json",
    "/downloads/log_test.txt",
    "/downloads/test_logs.sh"
  ]
}
```

Target json output:

```
{
  "start process": "Wed May 24 05:22:35 UTC 2017",
  "logfilename": "log_test",
  "start filelist": [
    "/downloads/json_log_array2object.jq",
    "/downloads/json_log_string2object.jq",
    "/downloads/log_test.json",
    "/downloads/log_test.txt",
    "/downloads/test_logs.sh"
  ]
}
```

bash script:

```
logfilename="log_test"

writelogstring2object() {
  exec 4>>"${1}.json"
  flock -x 4
  tee -a "$1.txt" | jq -sRf json_log_string2object.jq >&4
}

writelogarray2object() {
  exec 4>>"${1}.json"
  flock -x 4
  tee -a "$1.txt" | jq -nRf json_log_array2object.jq >&4
}

exec 3> >(writelogstring2object "$logfilename")
{
echo "start process: $(date -u)"
echo "logfilename:" $logfilename
} >&3
exec 3>&-
flock -s "$logfilename.json" -c :

exec 3> >(writelogarray2object "$logfilename")
{
echo "start filelist:"
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"/*
} >&3
exec 3>&-
flock -s "$logfilename.json" -c :
```

jq programs:

json_log_string2object.jq

```
def trim: sub("^ +";"") | sub(" +$";"");

def s2o:
  (index(":") // empty) as $ix
  | {(.[:$ix]): (.[$ix+1:]|trim)};

split("\n") | map(s2o) | add
```

json_log_array2object.jq

```
foreach (inputs,null) as $line ({};
   if $line == null then .emit = {(.key|tostring): .value}
   elif $line[-1:] == ":"
   then (if .key then {emit: {(.key): .value}} else null end)
        + { key : $line[0:-1] }
   else {key, value: (.value + [$line])}
   end;
   .emit // empty )
```

Appreciate approaches and examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To add two JSON objects, $one and $two, you can write `$one + $two`.
2. The two objects given at the beginning of the problem description are not quite valid as JSON.  Assuming that the file input.json contains the corrected text, the invocation:

   jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' input.json

yields the desired answer.

Comment: Thank you, that works very nicely to add the two objects, implemented as a function. How would you delete the previous objects? Or perhaps a solution would be to include the add within the creation of next object so that only one object is ever created in the log?

Comment: Trying to implement so that `writelogarray2object()` adds the file descriptor JSON object to the log file JSON object. But think that would only be a partial solution as it would still write another 'added' object to the log file. Trying to avoid post processing the JSON objects in the log file into a single JSON object log file, but not sure how else to do it?